# Swiping the view pager fragment should not move the tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

My program has a boolean variable name "isCorrect". I want, when isCorrect is false then the user should not able to open any other tab. (Either by swiping or by selecting tab). I tried to do this by below given logic but this cause the application to hang.

```
final boolean isCorrect=false;

tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                if(!isCorrect){
                    if(tab.getPosition()==1){
                        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    }
                }else{
                   mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a custom ViewPager subclass. The class inherits from ViewPager and includes a new method called setSwipeable to control if swipe events are enabled or not. Make sure to change layout file.

```
public class LockableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean swipeable;

    public LockableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public LockableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.swipeable = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.swipeable) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.swipeable) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void setSwipeable(boolean swipeable) {
        this.swipeable = swipeable;
    }
}
```

When flag is false disable swipe.

```
 if (!flag) {
        mViewPager.setSwipeable(false);
    } else {
        mViewPager.setSwipeable(true);
    }
```

Comment: Zohra Khan you are great, but it will not work as my requirement is. The value of flag is identified only when, when user swipe on screen. Then how it will work, can you explain a little bit more please.

Comment: @Dosti If you can explain me the problem scenario may be I can help more.